# php - How to remove date from an array having a same day of week

Tags: php

I want to remove date from an array by having same day of week from another array.

This was i try:

```
$intervalDates = ['2017-01-23','2017-01-24','2017-01-25','2017-01-26','2017-01-27','2017-01-28','2017-01-29','2017-01-30','2017-01-31','2017-02-01','2017-02-02','2017-02-03','2017-02-04','2017-02-05','2017-02-06','2017-02-07','2017-02-08','2017-02-09','2017-02-10'];

$tmpWeek = ['2016-10-28','2016-10-29','2016-10-30'];  



for($i = 0; $i < count($intervalDates); $i++){

    for($j = 0; $j < count($tmpWeek); $j++){

         if($intervalDates[$i]->dayOfWeek == $tmpWeek[$j]->dayOfWeek){
              unset($intervalDates[$i]);

              $intervalDates = array_values($intervalDates);


         }
   }
}
```

but I got the error undefined offset.

Please help.

Comment: can you add your current array

Comment: please add more code that's used before this code.

Comment: @user3099298 I add the array already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create day names array using `$tmpWeek`, then remove duplicate values from `$dayNames`. Then loop `$intervalDates` and remove same days and create new array.

```
$intervalDates = array('2016-10-28','2016-10-29','2016-10-30','2017-01-23','2017-01-24','2017-01-25','2017-01-26','2017-01-27','2017-01-28','2017-01-29','2017-01-30','2017-01-31','2017-02-01','2017-02-02','2017-02-03','2017-02-04','2017-02-05','2017-02-06','2017-02-07','2017-02-08','2017-02-09','2017-02-10');

$tmpWeek = array('2016-10-28','2016-10-29','2016-10-30');

// create day names array
$dayNames = array();
foreach($tmpWeek as $day){
    $dayNames[] = date('l', strtotime($day));
}
//  remove duplicate date names
$dayNames = array_unique($dayNames);

$data =array();
foreach($intervalDates as $date){
    if(!in_array(date('l', strtotime($date)), $dayNames)){
            $data[] = $date;
    }
}  

echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: sorry, I have typo on `$tmpWeek`, i want remove the same day of week

Comment: Which values you want to remove give me a example

Comment: I guess you are trying remove weekdays, and try to keep weekends isn't it?

Comment: for example 2016-10-28 is Friday, I want to remove all Friday in `$intervalDates`.

Comment: if i want remove the date is first of month? for extra knowledge

Answer (score 0):

You should `debug` your code by printing something inside `if statement` code. See for what value of `$i` or `$j` it is returning `undefined offset.` The error simply means that, you are using index for the array which is not defined on that array.

**What happened?**

You asked an array to give you the value given a key that it does not contain. It will give you the value NULL then put the above error in the errorlog.

It looked for your key in the array, and found undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
$intervalDates = ['2017-01-23', '2017-01-24', '2017-01-25', '2017-01-26', '2017-01-27', '2017-01-28', '2017-01-29', '2017-01-30', '2017-01-31', '2017-02-01', '2017-02-02', '2017-02-03', '2017-02-04', '2017-02-05', '2017-02-06', '2017-02-07', '2017-02-08', '2017-02-09', '2017-02-10'];

$tmpWeek = ['2016-10-28', '2016-10-29', '2016-10-30'];



for ($i = 0; $i < count($intervalDates); $i++) {

    for ($j = 0; $j < count($tmpWeek); $j++) {
        if (array_key_exists($i, $intervalDates) && array_key_exists($j, $tmpWeek)) {
            $dayofweek_1 = date('w', strtotime($intervalDates[$i]));

            $dayofweek_2 = date('w', strtotime($tmpWeek[$j]));


            if ($dayofweek_1 == $dayofweek_2) {
                unset($intervalDates[$i]);

                $intervalDates = array_values($intervalDates);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Update (If you want to remove all first dates):

```
for ($j = 0; $j < count($tmpWeek); $j++) {
        if (array_key_exists($i, $intervalDates) && array_key_exists($j, $tmpWeek)) {

            $dayofweek_1 = date('w', strtotime($intervalDates[$i]));
            $dayofweek_firstday = date('d', strtotime($intervalDates[$i]));
            $dayofweek_2 = date('w', strtotime($tmpWeek[$j]));


            if ($dayofweek_1 == $dayofweek_2 || $dayofweek_firstday == 1) {
                unset($intervalDates[$i]);

                $intervalDates = array_values($intervalDates);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: if i want remove the date is first of month? just for extra knowledge

Comment: Now you want to unset all first dates of every month? like 2016-10-01 ?

Comment: yup. It this possible?

Comment: Check now, I used OR operator, you can use AND operator if required.